Apply Jenkins worker credential from AWS secret manager
I want to securely handle Docker login credentials for my Jenkins worker node using the user data script. Instead of hardcoding the Docker username and password directly in the user data, is it possible to pull from AWS secret Manager via environment variables?
Retrieve Docker credentials from AWS Secrets Manager
DOCKER_USERNAME=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id my-docker-username --query "SecretString" --output text)
DOCKER_PASSWORD=$(aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id my-docker-password --query "SecretString" --output text)

Set up Docker registry authentication
echo "$DOCKER_PASSWORD" | sudo docker login -u "$DOCKER_USERNAME" --password-stdin

